# Read value of imported form component upon submit (without storing in state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I developed a component for ReactJS as to be used as a form item in conjunction with Antd's form. But, the `onFinish` callback function returns undefined for the value of my custom component. Probably, Antd's form is not being able to retrieve the value from my component. That does not happen when I am only using Antd components as form items.

On the example below, `MultipleEntry` is the component I have developed. `MultipleEntry` has a nested TextArea component.

```
function Sandbox(props) {

    return (
        <>
            <Form onFinish={(values) => console.log(values)}>
                <Form.Item name={'myComponent'}  >
                    <MultipleEntry />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>

        </>
    );
}


function MultipleEntry(props) {

    const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
    
    const Split = string =>
    {
        setValue(String(string).split(';'))
    }

    return (
        <TextArea
            onChange={(e) => {Split(e.target.value)}}
        />
    );
}
```

I thought about two alternatives here:

1. Storing the values of `MultipleEntry` in its internal state.
2. Storing the values of `MultipleEntry` on the parent component.

But, I dont want to store the values anywhere on the client's state, since the data inside the `MultipleEntry` component would be too big and impactful for performance.

How can I use Antd form's API to make it read the value of `MultipleEntry` as a form field, and populate the input parameter of `onFinish`?

Comment: It's better if you can provide a simple codesandbox version to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Diogo_Labres : since there was no feedback from you for a while, I assumed both solutions, suggested in my post are not relevant, so I deleted the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Yevgen. Unfortanily none of them solve the problem, but I will keep the question open in case someone knows the answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antd's FormItem behaves like a high-order component and passes some props to the child component.

So, if you are using any HTML form field elements like input, then FormItem will pass the onChange and value as props to input. Hence FormItem will control the value and onChange event of that element.

But having said above you will not be able to use the styling if some validation error is there in the FormItem.

Similarly Antd's component also usages native HTML form field elements and usages value and onChange. But on top of that, you will get the styles if there are any validation errors.

Here it comes your specific case, you can use onChange and value from props and utilize the same as following

```
function MultipleEntry(props) {
  const Split = e => {
    e.target.value = String(e.target.value).split(",");
    props.onChange(e);
  };

  return <input value={props.value} onChange={e => Split(e)} />;
}
```

If you are using any native HTML form elements then just split the props and pass it across the element like below

```
function MultipleEntry(props) {
  return <input {...props} />;
}
```

And for splitting you can use getValueFromEvent and then split the value there.

Here is the link for the modified sandbox to especially solve your problem https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-lake-65prw

Comment: Hi, sorry for my delayed to answer you. First of all, thank you for your time trying to solve this. But no, this isn't the answer to my problem. This issue's a POC, and it was reduced in a very simple way. The focus shouldn't be splitting text in the text input, but how to get a value of the state in the nested component using the form of Antd. The library offers other kinds of components and theses components have a very easy way to get the value through onFinish method. Sorry if the problem wasn't explicit enough.

Comment: the first half of my original answer tells about propagating the props to actual form field element. I have updated my answer for a better understanding of my original answer to your question. Let me know if it helps.